# Windows phone emulator not loading windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone app development. I am using an emulator. Every time i try to run the project emulator stops on windows phone starting and i get error "App development failed try again." I tried turning hyper-v on off repairing emulator update 3 . hyper-v Ethernet enable. What i am missing ??

Need Help

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified your machine meets the hardware requirements? <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx>

Answer (score 0):

I think the error would be "App deployment failed. Please try again." but not "App development failed. Please try again." :)

Anyways, please ensure you have following to get rid of the error,

- Minimum Hardware/software requirements (https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/oem?contentName=docs%2FGetting_Started%2FPreparing_for_Windows_Phone_development)
- Valid developer license/account to develop windows phone applications
- Enough free RAM (>2GB RAM should be free)
- Not more than one instance of VS is trying to use same emulator.

If everything is holds good then try following,

1. Restart emulator & check if it fixed the issue, if not go to next step.
2. Go to Hyper-V manager and delete all the virtual switches related to WP. If it doesn't fix issue go to next step.
3. Go to Hyper-V manager and delete all the windows phone virtual machines. repair WP SDK from control panel.

More info about troubleshooting errors like this can be found at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68/wp8-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?forum=wptools :)

Hope it helps